After upgrading to Fedora 41 I get a compile error with rpmbuild –rebuild
After upgrading from Fedora 38 to Fedora 41 I am getting a compile error with recompiling a source rpm package.
rpmbuild --rebuild package.fc41.src.rpm

error: passing argument 1 of ‘gzwrite’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
If I recompile this same source rpm package in a mock environment it compiles without error:
mock -r /etc/mock/fedora-41-x86_64.cfg --no-clean package.fc41.src.rpm

What is different about the mock environment? I checked both rpm --eval “%{optflags}” and rpm -E “%{build_ldflags}” in the mock shell and on the Fedora 41 machine and they matched. Why would the mock environment not give the
[-Wincompatible-pointer-types] error?

What package are you compiling? Is there a difference in gcc versions between your host and the mock environment? Does type -p gcc on your host return /usr/bin/gcc or something else?

type -p gcc
/usr/lib64/ccache/gcc
sudo dnf provides /usr/lib64/ccache/gcc
ccache-4.10.2-1.fc41.x86_64 : C/C++ compiler cache
sudo dnf remove ccache
type -p gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
The compile results are the same as before
rpmbuild --rebuild aubit4gl-1.6.1.p4-2.fc41.src.rpm
